# Stop one event by another - Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm implementing drag and drop with jQuery.
So, after mousedown, event starts working:
On mousemove selected element moves with mouse.
Now, I want it to stop working on mouseup.
here's my code:

```
$(document).on("mousemove", widget, function() {

    var newMouseX = event.pageX - mouseX;
    var newMouseY = event.pageY - mouseY;

    var newElemX = elemX + newMouseX;
    var newElemY = elemY + newMouseY;

    $(widget).offset({ top: newElemY , left: newElemX });

    $(document).on("mouseup", widget, function(widget) {
        // what to do here?
    });
});
```

any suggestions?

Comment: careful here - you're re-registering the `mouseup` event handler _every single time the mouse moves_!

Comment: aw... you're right... that's horrible, i'll change it

Comment: jQuery already has inbuilt drag and drop functions, consider that too

Comment: @TinoMThomas don't you need jQuery UI for that?

Comment: Thanks but it's a task of the project I'm doing for my university. I have to do it...

Comment: @Alnitak Yes, you need to load jQueryUI for implementing those methods.

Comment: `widget = null` worked perfectly (variable widget is the element i'm dragging)